# NTFS file owner is able to delete a file with read permission

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs

I have a file on NTFS partition, and I'm the owner of this file .

I have the read permission only on this file and no other permissions are set.

I tried to delete the file thinking it will show "Access is Denied " message ,but i was able to delete the file !

I created a folder and tried the same ,but I was not able to delete it !

how is that possible to delete a file with read permission only ? is it because I'm the owner or using administrator account?

if so , why the same rule don't apply on folders ?

Here is a .gif image to show you what I mean:
[image]

Regards

Comment: Please Instead of giving negative feedback , ask me in the comments if there was anything unclear

Comment: xp is EOL so offtopic on serverfault.com

Comment: I know , but people need to learn and the same rule apply to newer Operating Systems  , all I saw was negative opinion about this topic  , sorry for asking and the Moderator can delete my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NTFS, owner implicitly and effectively (you can write DACL, granting yourself any permission) has full permissions on files (IIRC folders as well), despite DACL entries. [Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc749445(v=ws.10))

Workaround is to use special SID in DACL: [S-1-3-4 "Owner Rights"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/security-identifiers#well-known-sids)

It replaces implicit permissions with explicit ones defined by you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply , Forgive my poor knowledge the owner can assign himself any permission ,but in my case why other permissions like modify the contents of the file don't apply ? only the read (to view the contents of the file ) which explicitly defined  and delete (to delete the file itself - implicitly defined ) would apply ?  and why the same scenario won't apply to folders and files and subfolders that are contained within ?

Comment: I Uploaded a gif image in the question above , please take a look for better understanding and thanks in advanced .

Comment: Your GIF is on XP. On Windows 10 I get access denied on CLI and UAC/admin prompt for GUI. THB, I would think that this could be a small behavioral change between OS versions, or Explorer does some silent ACL fixup in the background. I have some faint (possibly false) memory that Owner used to mean something different a long ago but can't find any reference to that, it has probably long since been removed from online documentation. Maybe I'll spin up a an ancient VM later to try it out myself later.